# Filemaker Alternatives

Tags: ios, macos, relational-database

I'm looking for an alternative to FileMaker Pro. I've been playing with a trial for a week now.
I'm looking for a rapid application development platform for small relational databases to run on iOS and OS X

Things I like about FM

- Can make reasonable looking layouts quite quickly.
- Can access the database from an iPad with Filemaker Go.

Things I don't like about FM

- EVERYTHING takes a half a dozen clicks.  In particular constructing a script with mouse clicks is painful.
- The number of modal dialog boxes is astounding.  It is routine to have them layered 3 deep.
- Syntax is verbose.  Set Variable [ $name Value:value ]  Some of the examples start to look like excel formulas.  (Excel is a write only language....) Or COBOL.
- Near as I can figure variable scope is either local or global.  If a script calls a script, you must call it with any local variables you want it to have access to.
- Debugging is very difficult in the FM Pro version.
- Doesn't seem to be any provision for building a library of functions in a single file.
- No clear and obvious guide to how to document your database so that it can be maintained.
- No clear and obvious way to print out all your scripts.
- No clear and obvious way to print out a calling tree/dependency tree.
- No clear guide to best practices.

Comment: FileMaker 16 is significantly improved in some of these areas, although I recognise this is somewhat subjective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: Despite it's shortcomings (and I'll admit it has many), FileMaker is still the best rapid-development platform for OS X and iOS (and Windows, for that matter). The closest second-place (for OS X/iOS) I can think of would be Cocoa/Cocoa Touch with Core Data with Ruby on Rails for a web interface a distant third.

Having said that, I can offer a few tips for some of your complaints:

- If you're a keyboard-centric person like myself, turn on Full Keyboard Access (in the Keyboard System Preference within the Shortcuts tab). This will allow you to tab through all of the controls, such as buttons, which makes it much easier to select deep dialog options from the keyboard. For example, when building a script, you can use the tab key to focus on the list of script steps, then type a few letters of the step you want, which will highlight it, and press return, which will add it to the script. Then, while a script step in the script is highlighted, you can use Ctrl-Up and Ctrl-Down to move the step up and down in the execution order.
- Script variables, both local and global, can be set within any calculation. For example, if you're capturing a primary key value to a local variable and you already have an `If` script step, you can do the capture within the `If` script step.

  ```
  If[ Let( [ $record_id = Table::ID ]; not IsEmpty( $record_id ) ) ]
  ```

  Similarly, if you have a number of `Set Variable` script steps in a row, you can combine them into one:

  ```
  Set Variable[ $? Value:Let( [ $var1 = 1; $var2 = "two" ] ) "" ]
  ```

  This sets the `$?` variable to an empty string, but has the side effect of also setting `$var1` and `$var2`.
- You're correct that variables are either local to a script (or calculation) or global to the file. If you want to share information between scripts, parameters are the solution. For my personal solution for sending multiple parameters to a script, read my article on [Multiple FileMaker Script Parameters](http://chivalrysoftware.com/index.php/blog/87-multiple-filemaker-script-parameters).
- If you're going to do any amount of custom development with FileMaker, you really want to get FileMaker Pro Advanced, which, inaddition to a step-level debugger, offers the ability to create custom menus and, my personal favorite, custom functions. Using custom functions (which can easily be brought from one file to another), you can built a complex library of functions.
- To print out all of your scripts, open `Manage Scripts`, select all of the scripts with Cmd-A and click the print button on the bottom right of the window.
- For script dependencies, look into [BaseElements](http://www.goya.com.au/baseelements), a FileMaker-based solution for documenting FileMaker systems.
- While there's no standard "best practices" across the board, and because of how FileMaker organizes its objects, documentation is often found in various places (script comments, calculation comments, field comments), there are many ways to build a system in FileMaker so that you increase its maintainability. Unlike Objective-C or PHP, where you can be fairly certain where the comment for something will be (either in the declaration or at its first use), FileMaker is more flexible. The important idea behind "best practices" and documentation, in my opinion, is consistency. If you comment a field by using the field comments, always comment fields that way, don't comment calculation fields within the calculation or use dummy validation to put comments in a calculation there.

If you're looking for one guide (but not the only guide) for best practices, check out [FileMaker Coding Standards](http://filemakerstandards.org/display/cs/Overview). I use some of those guidelines, and others are my own that have evolved over time.

Finally, if you're looking for generally great material on how to get the most from FileMaker, check out [FileMaker Magazine](http://www.filemakermagazine.com), published by one of the people involved with the FileMaker Coding Standards site.

The truth is, if you're coming from some more conventional development platform, FileMaker is going to take a bit of getting used to. I've been using it for over 20 years, so I'll admit it's probably difficult for me to completely empathize with that situation. But if you give it a bit of a chance, I think you'll find that there's no other platform available that can build complex database systems for OS X and iOS so quickly.

Comment: Good answer.  Thanks.  One other useful book:  Filemaker -- The Missing Manual.

Answer (score 2):

Filemaker takes a lot of getting used to, it's very different to SQL or any of the mainstream taught languages so if you have done some training you will need to re-think how to get to the same end goal.
If you are serious about it then get Filemaker Pro Advanced v14 and that should fix some of your GUI editing issues and join developer.filemaker.com and do the training course that you can download from there.

Once doing that and getting some experience you will find Filemaker is very RAD.  Also there IS a way to get around any shortcomings, everything is possible in Filemaker.

As for passing multiple parameters to a script a quick and easy way to do it for 99.5% of cases is to do this:

- Calling the script - In the parameters box separate your parameters with a carraige return like so: "parameter 1" & "¶" & "parameter 2" & "¶" & "parameter 3" etc.
- In your receiving script use `GetValue(get(scriptparameter),1)` for parameter 1, 2 for 2, etc.
- This technique won't work when you are trying to pass text with carraige returns but that is the exception.